# where can I get a good SDEF editor?

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, sdef

I'm writing an objective C program which will need to be applescriptable. so, I need to create and edit an SDF file. I'd MUCH rather not have to write XML if I don't have to, so I'm hoping that someone can point me to a good editor... I've found [SDEF EDitor](http://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/sdefeditor.php) but I'd like a couple of options to play around with...

Surprisingly, the applescript editor itself doesn't allow you to edit SDEF files... hrm...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDEF Editor is pretty much the only game in town, as far as I know.